# Why does IntlDateFormatter not return "false" even with obviously made-up locale/language strings?

Tags: php, intldateformatter

**Source:**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php

**Quote:**

> Return Values ¶
> The created IntlDateFormatter or **FALSE in case of failure**.

**Code:**

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "en_US" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
var_dump($fmt);

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter( "madeupfakenonexistent" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  );
var_dump($fmt);
```

**Actual output:**

```
object(IntlDateFormatter)#3 (0) {
}
object(IntlDateFormatter)#2 (0) {
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
object(IntlDateFormatter)#3 (0) {
}
bool(false)
```

**PHP:**

7.4.12

**Conclusion:**

The manual is lying or I'm misinterpreting it.

Comment: The PHP manual is written by the community, so rather than saying it is "lying", you could just say "needs correcting", and once you're sure you could submit the correction yourself, which can now be done [via a github pull request](https://github.com/php/doc-en).

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the manual, but it does also appear to be incorrect.

Your first mistake is that a constructor in PHP *cannot* return anything other than an object of the specified type. The only way it can signal an error is by throwing an exception. That page however also documents the static method `IntlDateFormatter::create` and the plain function `datefmt_create`, both of which *could* return false.

Your second mistake is assuming that "returns false on error" means that every possible error will be detected and return false. In this particular case, there appears to be no validation of whether the locale specified matches one in any particular list. Passing unexpected values for other parameters *is* considered an error, e.g. `$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter ("en_US", 99999, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'America/Los_Angeles', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);`.

Where you appear to be accidentally correct is that none of these functions appear to return `false` for such errors. For `new IntlDateFormatter`, that will trigger an exception, because it can't do anything else; for `IntlDateFormatter::create` and `datefmt_create` it will return `null`, which is the standard PHP behaviour for bad arguments [as noted here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php).

I'm not 100% sure, but looking at [the relevant source code](https://heap.space/xref/php-src/ext/intl/dateformat/dateformat_create.cpp) I don't think there are any cases where these functions return `false`, so the manual should perhaps be corrected/updated.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed in PHP. See [Issue #12282](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12282).